# ApexCharts.js Line Chart - Display percent from total in tooltip

Tags: apexcharts

I want to display percent instead of an integer.
Now it simply shows the value as integer when hovering on the data point of the chart (the tooltip).

I think I need to set in the formatter formula like this:

```
let test = value / SUM(all_values)
return test.toFixed(0) + '%'
```

But, I could not find it in their documentation, the best I found is this one which always gives me 100%, per every data point:

```
    tooltip: {
      y: {
        formatter: function(value, opts) {
                let percent = opts.w.globals.seriesPercent[opts.seriesIndex][opts.dataPointIndex];
                return percent.toFixed(0) + '%'

        }
      }
    }
```

[image: Gives me wrong value of 100% per each data point]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right that you'll need to use the tooltip formatter, but the array you're using to get the percentage values isn't correct.

If you log the values `opts.w.globals.seriesPercent` you'll find that it's all 100's:

`[[100, 100, 100, ..., 100]]`

(I suspect this might be because it's intended to be used with other chart types.)

You can still get the percentage though, it'll just need to be worked out.

Using your same method to format the tooltip, but getting the values from `opts.series` instead:

```
    tooltip: {
        y: {
          formatter: function(value, opts) {
              const sum = opts.series[0].reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
              const percent = (value / sum) * 100;
              return percent.toFixed(0) + '%'
          },
        },
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">



<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">





  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"

    integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">







  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>

  <script src="app/app.js"></script>



  <script>

    let apiLabels = [];

    let apiData = [];

    let currentTimestamp = (Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)).toString();



    //use this URL for daily fetch

    //let url = "https://aave-api-v2.aave.com/data/rates-history?reserveId=0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb480xb53c1a33016b2dc2ff3653530bff1848a515c8c5&resolutionInHours=24&from="+currentTimestamp;



    let url = "https://aave-api-v2.aave.com/data/rates-history?reserveId=0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb480xb53c1a33016b2dc2ff3653530bff1848a515c8c5&resolutionInHours=24&from=1639813032";

    // months list

    const monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];



    // fetch from api

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {

      if (this.readyState === 4) {

        let myData = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

        console.log(myData);

        for (let i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {

          //let formedDate = (myData[i]['x']['year']+'-'+myData[i]['x']['month']+'-'+myData[i]['x']['date']).toString();



          let formedDate = monthNames[myData[i]['x']['month']] + ' ' + myData[i]['x']['date'];

          console.log(formedDate);



          let formedLiquidData = (myData[i]['liquidityRate_avg'] * 100).toFixed(2);





          console.log(formedLiquidData+"%");



          apiLabels.push(formedDate);

          apiData.push(formedLiquidData);

        }



            const data = {

            labels: apiLabels,

            datasets: [

            {

              label: "USDC",

              borderColor: "rgb(180,11,107)",

              data: apiData

            }

          ]

        };

        

             const config = {

              type: "line",

              data: data,

              options:{


             scales: {

              y: {

                ticks: {

                 callback: function (value, index, values) {

                    return value + '%';

                    }

                   }

                },

              },

              },

          };

          
              
           

            

          

          





    const myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart"), config);

        }

      });

    xhr.open(

      "GET",

      url

    );

    xhr.send();





  </script>

  </div>

  <div id="app"></div>



  <title>brew</title>

  <style>

    body {

      background-color: white;

    }



    .center-form {

      width: 80%;

      margin: auto;

    }



    #title {

      color: teal;

      text-align: center;

    }





    .waitlist {

      position: relative;

      z-index: 3;

      width: 146px;

      height: 30px;

      margin-top: 60px;

      border-style: solid;

      border-width: 1px;

      border-color: #081852;

      background-color: transparent;

      box-shadow: -10px 10px 0 0 #081852;

      color: #081852;

      font-size: 12px;

      line-height: 30px;

      font-weight: 400;

      text-align: center;

      letter-spacing: 0.21px;

      position: fixed;

      right: 3%;

      top: -5%;

    }



    .waitlist-button {

      display: inline-block;

      padding: 9px 15px;

      background-color: #3898EC;

      color: white;

      border: 0;

      line-height: inherit;

      text-decoration: none;

      cursor: pointer;

      border-radius: 0;

    }





    .box-prices {

      padding: 20px;

      width: 200px;

      height: auto;

      color: #000;

      /* background-color: #fff; */

      border: 4px solid #1c1c53;

      border-radius: 2px;

    }







    .dropbtn {

      background-color: navy;

      color: white;

      padding: 16px;

      font-size: 16px;

      border: none;

    }





    .dropdown-content {

      display: none;

      position: absolute;

      background-color: #f1f1f1;

      min-width: 160px;

      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

      z-index: 1;

    }



    .dropdown-content a {

      color: black;

      padding: 12px 16px;

      text-decoration: none;

      display: block;

    }



    .dropdown-content a:hover {

      background-color: #ddd;

    }





    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {

      display: block;

    }





    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {

      background-color: #0b95f1;

    }





    footer {

      display: flex;

      justify-content: space-between;

    }



    .myChart {

      width: 50%;

      height: 40px;

    }



    /* Decorative */

    a {

      text-decoration: none;

      color: #555;

    }







    footer {

      background-color: #82cdf8;

      padding: 20px 40px;



    }



    .right {

      float: left;

      text-align: center;

    }



    .article {

      color: white;

    }

  </style>

</head>



<body>





  <img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/61768faf04d20bf3487b5a2a/6176a6363e64b8d84e32d0b7_brew-icon-256px-v2.png"

    loading="eager" width="55" height="55" alt="Brew" class="img-logo" position="absolute" top="-3%" left="7;">

  <!-------------- title------------------------>



  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-12 mt-2">

        <h1 style="color: #1c98">

          Stablecoin Deposits on Aave

        </h1>

        <a data-w-id="14f1dfb2-926f-581f-7faa-3f62171b1db3" href="" class="waitlist waitlist-button">Join the

          waitlist</a>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>





  <!------------------------AAVE PRICE ------------>



  <div class="container">

    <div class="row mt-5">

      <div class="col-md-6">

        <div class="aave-prices">

          <p>AAVE PRICE</p>

          <p>$172.8</p>

          <p>16%</p>

        </div>

      </div>



      <!------------------------AAVE DESCRIPTION ------------>



      <div class="col-md-6">

        <h1>What is AAVE ?</h1>

        <p>Aave is an open source and non-custodial liquidity protocol for earning

          interest on deposits and borrowing assets.</p>

      </div>

    </div>









    <!------------------------AAVe CHAIN ------------>



    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-12 mt-3">

        <button class="dropbtn">CHAIN</button>

        <div class="dropdown-content">

          <a href="#">Polygon</a>

          <a href="#">Ethereum</a>

          <a href="#">Avalance</a>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>



  <!------graph----->

  <div>

    <canvas id="myChart" height="50" weidth="50"></canvas>

  </div>









  <!-- calculator -->

  <div class="container mt-5" style="border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 5px;">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-12">

        <h1 id="title">How Much You Can Earn ?</h1>

      </div>

    </div>

    <br>



    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-6">

        <form>

          <div class="form-group mt-2">

            <label class="form-group">Amount</label>

            <input class="form-control mt-2" type="text" id="principal" placeholder="&#36;">

          </div>

          <div class="form-group mt-2">

            <label class="form-group">Interest rate:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;4%</label>

          </div>

          <div class="form-group mt-2">

            <label class="form-group">Compound Freequency:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Daily</label>

          </div>



          <div class="form-group mt-2">

            <label class="form-group">Payout Freequency:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Monthly</label>

          </div>



          <button class="btn btn-block btn-info mt-3" type="button" onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>

        </form>

      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">







        <form style="padding-top: 70px;">

          <div class="form-group mt-2">

            <label class="form-group">Interest rate:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;5%</label>

          </div>

          <div class="form-group mt-2">

            <label class="form-group">Compound Freequency:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Daily</label>

          </div>



          <div class="form-group mt-2">

            <label class="form-group">Payout Freequency:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Monthly</label>

          </div>

        </form>



      </div>

    </div>

    <br>





    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-6">

        <h5 class="total">Result USD</h5>

        <h1 id="USD"></h1>

      </div>



      <div class="col-md-6">

        <h5 class="total">Result USDT</h5>

        <h1 id="USDC"></h1>

      </div>

    </div>





  </div>

  <!-- calculator end -->

  <div>

    <canvas id="myChart_subbagain" height="50" weidth="50" top="80%"></canvas>

  </div>

  <!----footer-->





  <div class="col-md-12 mt-5">

    <footer>

      <div class="col-md-6">

        <img src="/dawnload.png" alt="" width="150">

      </div>



      <div class="col-md-6">

        <section class="right">

          <a href="https://www.brew.money/">Join Brew Today</a>

          <article>USDC is not a legal tender recognised by US or any other government. Unlike a bank account, your

            deposit is not insured. While Brew will make every effort to ensure that your deposit earn the best interest

            rates in the most secure way possible, please note that any investment entails risk. Interest Rates are

            subject to change anytime as per the market conditions.</article>

        </section>

      </div>

    </footer>

  </div>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">



  function calculate() {

    var principle = 0;

    var interest = 5 / 100;

    var numberOfPeriod = 12;

    var time = 10;

    var CI = 0;



    principle = document.getElementById("principal").value;



    // CI = ((p * (1 + i) ^ n) - p);



    CI = principle * (1 + interest / numberOfPeriod) ^ (numberOfPeriod * time);



    document.getElementById("USD").innerHTML = CI;

    document.getElementById("USDC").innerHTML = CI;



  }

</script>



<!------cal graph-->



</html>
```

Comment: please any one tell how i will add tooltips with % symbole